# Social icon hover effect smaller

Tags: html, css

I found this really neat css3 fiddle. 
http://dabblet.com/gist/8255020

I experimented some with the code. But somehow I can't get my head around it. Can somebody please give me some more information on how this works? I would really like this to use .social with width and heights of max 50px in stead of 100px (which is way to big for in a website).

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Demo: [50px Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/zarx87j7/)

#### Changes: [Diff of the two CSSes](http://www.mergely.com/fVzkllXK/)

- Each social icon is composed of two `div`s.

  - `.back` is facing the viewer ie. no rotation applied - `transform:rotateY(0deg);`
  - `.front` is rotated 100deg around its y (vertical axis) in 3d space therefore becoming the left side of a cube -  `transform:rotateY(10deg);`
  - both `div`s have `translateZ(21px)` applied, so in 3D space they're moved further away from the "viewer" therefore appearing smaller and getting hidden behind the frontal one.
- On `:hover`

  - the whole `.social` element is rotated around Y (in 3D space) therefore the `.front` will be visible (which was up until now the left side of the cube) and `.back` becomes hidden (right side of the cube)

Note: `.social` has also [`transform-style: preserve-3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) otherwise inner elements would lose the 3D effect.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really nice fiddle.